# R: Iterate over pairs of columns in dataframe by regex match

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to iterate over pairs of columns in a dataframe.  Every column will have a corresponding column with a "_ans" suffix (and identical prefix).  I need to create new column with the suffix "_score" if the "_ans" column and the comparison column are equal.

Reproducible example:

```
    set.seed(42)
    df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 10 * 5, replace = TRUE),
    ncol = 10, dimnames = list(NULL, c("CB1", "LB2", "CW3", "WC1",
    "LW20", "CB1_ans", "LB2_ans", "CW3_ans", "WC1_ans", "LW20_ans"))))

> df
  CB1 LB2 CW3 WC1 LW20 CB1_ans LB2_ans CW3_ans WC1_ans LW20_ans
1   3   9   6   9    1       7       3       2       5        1
2   3   3   4   2    5       1       3       7       4        4
3   7   7   7   1    7       6       4       6       3        4
4   5   8   7   5    2       6       2       7       2        3
5   6   3   3   2    3       1       9       9       1        4
```

If I would do this manually, it would look like:

```
df$CB1_score <- df$CB1 == df$CB1_ans
df$LB2_score <- df$LB2 == df$LB2_ans
df$CB3_score <- df$CW3 == df$CW3_ans
```

Resulting output:

```
  CB1 LB2 CW3 WC1 LW20 CB1_ans LB2_ans CW3_ans WC1_ans LW20_ans CB1_score LB2_score CB3_score
1   3   9   6   9    1       7       3       2       5        1     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
2   3   3   4   2    5       1       3       7       4        4     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
3   7   7   7   1    7       6       4       6       3        4     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
4   5   8   7   5    2       6       2       7       2        3     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE
5   6   3   3   2    3       1       9       9       1        4     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

And so on.  I have been working on this for an hour trying to figure out a way to automate this without for loops, but cannot think of the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `purrr:map`:

```
map(c("CB1", "LB2", "CW3", "WC1", "LW20"), ~ df %>%
    mutate(
        !!(paste0(.x, "_score", collapse = "")) :=
            UQ(rlang::sym(.x)) == UQ(rlang::sym(paste0(.x, "_ans", collapse = ""))) )) %>%
    reduce(., left_join)
#  CB1 LB2 CW3 WC1 LW20 CB1_ans LB2_ans CW3_ans WC1_ans LW20_ans CB1_score
#1   9   5   5   9    9       5       7       8       4        9     FALSE
#2   9   7   7   9    2       4       8       1       4        8     FALSE
#3   3   2   9   2    9       9       4       2       1        6     FALSE
#4   8   6   3   5    9       5       7       9       9        9     FALSE
#5   6   7   5   6    1       8       1       6       4        6     FALSE
#  LB2_score CW3_score WC1_score LW20_score
#1     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
#2     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#3     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
#4     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
#5     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
```

Comment: Wow... no wonder I couldn't find a tidyverse solution.  I don't think I have seen a single one of these functions

Comment: @Parseltongue `purrr::map` is very similar to base R's `Map`; a lot of the extra functions are `rlang` syntax and deal with having `mutate` recognise dynamically created column names as such. For example, the bang-bang operator `!!` evaluates an expression in the surrounding context, which in this case are the dynamically constructed column names `CB1_score`, `LB2_score`, and so on. There might be a different/simpler `tidyverse` solutions;-) but `purrr::map` offers a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

One base-R solution:

```
nms <- colnames(df)
ans <- nms[grepl("_ans$", nms)]
qstn <- gsub("_ans$", "", ans)
# in case there's something wrong with the names??
ans <- ans[ qstn %in% nms ]
qstn <- qstn[ qstn %in% nms ]


scores <- df[qstn] == df[ans]
colnames(scores) <- paste0(qstn, "_score")
cbind(df, scores)
#   CB1 LB2 CW3 WC1 LW20 CB1_ans LB2_ans CW3_ans WC1_ans LW20_ans CB1_score LB2_score CW3_score
# 1   9   5   5   9    9       5       7       8       4        9     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
# 2   9   7   7   9    2       4       8       1       4        8     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
# 3   3   2   9   2    9       9       4       2       1        6     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
# 4   8   6   3   5    9       5       7       9       9        9     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
# 5   6   7   5   6    1       8       1       6       4        6     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
#   WC1_score LW20_score
# 1     FALSE       TRUE
# 2     FALSE      FALSE
# 3     FALSE      FALSE
# 4     FALSE       TRUE
# 5     FALSE      FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

One base R option would be to iterate over all columns in your data frame which *don't* end in `_ans`, and then compare them against their `_ans` counterparts.  We can use `grepl` and `sapply` here:

```
cols <- names(df)[grepl("^(?!.*_ans).*$", names(df), perl=TRUE)]
for (name in cols) {
    df[paste0(name, "_score")] <- df[[name]] == df[[paste0(name, "_ans")]]
}

df

  CB1_score LB2_score CW3_score WC1_score LW20_score
1 FALSE    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
2 FALSE    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
3 FALSE    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
4 FALSE    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE       TRUE
5 FALSE    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      FALSE
```

### Demo